# GIf Resource in delphi

Tags: delphi, resources, gif

I'm trying to do a simple resource(GIF) opening in delphi, 
res.RC file :

```
Loading RCDATA "loadingAd.gif"
```

Code:

```
{$R *.dfm}
{$R res.RES}

procedure TForm1.Image1Click(Sender: TObject);
var h : THandle;
begin
   h := FindResource(HInstance, 'Loading', 'RCDATA');
   showmessage(IntToStr(h))
end;
```

But every time i get 0, i'm using XE4 so i tried maybe :

```
{$R *.dfm}
{$R res.RES}

procedure TForm1.Image1Click(Sender: TObject);
var h : THandle;
begin
   h := FindResource(HInstance, PChar('Loading'), PChar('RCDATA'));
   showmessage(IntToStr(h))
end;
```

Still getting "Resource not found".

Comment: Are you sure you've compiled the resource? Are you having this problem when trying to compile or try to read it?

Comment: yep, i compiled with the BRCC32, and im having that when i click the button?

Comment: Try compiling / reading the resource name in all caps `LOADING` I've seen problems if you don't use caps.

Comment: Same thing .. did not work

Comment: Also, in Delphi XE4, you can add resources without using a resource script. Go to `Project > Resources and Images`

Comment: Yea, i tried that first ...

Comment: Well if it doesn't work when you use the built-in method, then something isn't right. Are you `building`, `compiling`, or `running` your application when testing? Make sure the resource gets properly attached by doing a full `build`.

Comment: Does this have to do with it : `[dcc32 Hint] H2161 Warning: Duplicate resource:  Type 10 (RCDATA), ID GIFIMAGE_1; File C:\Users\evilkid\Desktop\pascal\Project1.dres resource kept; file C:\Users\evilkid\Desktop\pascal\Project1.dres resource discarded.`

Comment: Well that might be since you tried both methods - it should still work...?

Comment: Well i removed the `{$R Project1.dres}` and i got rid of that message, but still no resource omg ... and i can see the Gif in the project manager

Comment: AH, it accepted BMP images ...

Comment: First things first, verify the basic assumptions. Have you tried opening the EXE in Resource Hacker to ensure that your GIF is getting linked into the application?

Comment: Alternatively you can include any file as raw data into DFM itself, then extract it to something like TMemorystream

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're searching for the resource under the wrong resource type. The string `'RCDATA'` is not the same as the constant `RT_RCDATA`, which is actually the integer 10 coerced to have type `PChar`. Use that instead of the string literal. If the resource still isn't found, verify using a resource browser that your program really contains the resources you expect it to.